# Testing calls to an akka actor in Play

Tags: scala, testing, playframework, akka, actor

I have refactored a bunch of email sending code in a play application to do that asynchronously using an actor.

When I need to send an email, I now have an injection of an `EmailActor` and I call `emailActor ? EmailRequest(from, to, ...)` to send it.

My question is, how can I unit test that the actor is actually called ?

I read the documentation of Akka regarding tests, but it seems to me it focuses on testing the actor themselves, not their invocation, and it is not clear at all where I should start.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`TestProbe`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/testing.html#replying-to-messages-received-by-probes) and inject it into your email service. Check out this simple test case

```scala
import akka.actor.{ActorRef, ActorSystem}
import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.testkit.{TestKit, TestProbe}
import akka.util.Timeout
import org.scalatest.flatspec.AsyncFlatSpecLike

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class TestProbeActorExample
    extends TestKit(ActorSystem("test"))
    with AsyncFlatSpecLike {

  class MyService(actorRef: ActorRef) {
    def sendEmail(email: String): Future[Int] = {
      implicit val timeout: Timeout = 1.second
      (actorRef ? email).mapTo[Int]
    }
  }

  it should "test an actor" in {
    val testProbe = TestProbe()
    val service = new MyService(testProbe.ref)
    val statusCode = service.sendEmail("email")
    testProbe.expectMsg("email")
    testProbe.reply(10)
    statusCode.map(r => assert(r == 10))
  }
}
```

Please note if you use `ask` pattern you need to assert that a message has been received with `expectMsg` and then you have to send a reply back with `reply`

Comment: Here you instanciate `new MyService(...)` in the test... in my case the service is instanciated and injected in the controller by Guice, so I cannot proceed the same

Comment: @Weier are you testing the controller or the service?

Comment: If you are relying on Giuce to do the injection, you need to create custom bindings as defined here https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaTestingWithGuice